# PHP/MySQL only update input fields that have been changed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Creating a little admin row updater that I can't figure out in PHP server-side.  I want the sql query to just update $_POST fields which have been altered on the page, that way it won't cycle all 100 or so records.

Here is my approach:

1) jQuery listen to changed input fields, then assign name attribute user-field-updated

2) PHP detects user-field-updated is set.

3) On submit reload, PHP detects this input, updates to SQL by row ID.  How do I make sure PHP knows which input field goes to which row ID?

jQuery client-side update name attribute:

```
    $(".listen").keyup(function() { 
        $(this).attr("name", "user-field-updated");
        })
```

Generate HTML admin table that is like a simple version of phpmyadmin:

```
<form action="post">
<?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
<tr>
    <td>The editable field: <input class="listen" type="text" name="user-field" size="4" value="<?php echo $rows['Users'] ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $rows['ID']; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Click to update only fields I changed" />
</form>
```

At the bottom of my page is php script which will trigger on reload:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {

    foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
        if(isset($_POST['user-count-updated'])){
            $ID = $_POST['ID'];
            $sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET $name = $value WHERE id = '$ID'";
            $q->execute($db->prepare($sql)); 
        }
    }

};
```

A question that could be asked is: In PHP, how do I "group" related values in a form submit that will update different rows in a database? How can I make PHP know which row I want to update with the field input.

---

### Solution created based on jacouh

jQuery changes input name attribute of text field AND inserts a new hidden input to trigger the isset variable below..

```
    $(".trigger-changed").keyup(function() { 
        $(this).addClass("changed");
        $(this).attr("name", $(this).data("name")).off("keyup");
        $("#mainform").append('<input type="hidden" name="user-updated"></input>')
        })
```

html

```
<td><input type="text" size="4" name="nochange" data-name="userfield@<?php echo $rows['ID'] ?>" value="<?php echo $rows['Users'] ?>" class="trigger-changed"></input></td>
```

php detect an input has changed (just a general global trigger, not specific to the field itself).  Then go ahead and parse out the name value.  If successful reload.

```
if(isset($_POST['user-updated'])) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if($name != 'nochange'){
            $name = strtok($key, '@');
            $ID = strtok("\n");
            $sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET Users = $value WHERE ID = '$ID'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if($result){
                echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php\">";
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I also consulted a friend who suggested a myriad of ways from constructing a new array to printing out hidden input tags into the html itself.  I think this solution is most compact for a simple change.

Comment: Your PHP part, what is $name variable in sql query? Is it always 'user-field'?

Comment: For one thing, you need to change `id = $ID"` to `id = '$ID'"`

Comment: I don't think I presented or asked this question correctly. But anyway, my JS alters user-field to become user-field-updated.  It was a way of having PHP know if that variable was set.  I'm wondering if I should just have PHP create a new array and then cycle through that in the SQL update.

Comment: Is there always one field per row, or could there be multiple fields per row which could change? The answer is different if only one field is changed per row, with multiple fields you would need some kind of array syntax for your inputs.

Comment: not looked at the PHP part in detail but I noticed that you have your form `action` as `POST`, instead, the `method` should be `POST` and the `action` should be the url of your server side script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You print a bunch of inputs with same names in your loop, there's no way to differentiate them on submit.

Try something like that: HTML (I rewrote a bit, the point is inside input tag)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc())
    echo "<input
        name='no'
        data-name='fieldname@" . $row['ID'] . "'
        value='...'>";
```

JS:

```
$(".listen").keyup(function() { 
    $(this).attr("name", $(this).data("name")).off("keyup");
})
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    if($name != 'no'){
        $name = strtok($key, '@');
        $ID = strtok("\n");
        // here you will have $name
        //      (== "fieldname" from html example), $ID and $value
    }
```

Comment: Oh interesting! Just store all the variables into each input tag as attributes.  I didn't know PHP could read them.

Comment: @liquified PHP reads `name` and `value`. So, you store all the needed attributes in the `name` and then parse it. I suggested dividing with `@`, ubt there are other ways.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to correct somme errors first, as it's difficult to see PHP script errors when called with AJAX.

As all records are in a single form, we must identify each record individually like "**user-field123-updated**":

js:

```
$(".listen").keyup(function() {
  var myname = $(this).attr("name");
  if(! myname.match(/updated/i)) {
    $(this).attr("name", myname + "-updated");
  }
})
```

HTML while () {} loop, user name will be identified by user-field123:

```
<form action="post">
<?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td>Whatever this row name is: <?php echo $rows['Name']; ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $rows['ID']; ?></td>
    <td>The editable field: <input class="listen" type="text" name="user-field<?php echo $rows['ID']; ?>" size="4" value="<?php echo $rows['Users']; ?>"></input></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Click to update only fields I changed"></input>
</form>
```

PHP to save in DB, syntax:

```
//
// Users table $tbl_name must be set before:
//
if(isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {
    //
    // IDs is an array:
    //
    $IDs = $_POST['ID'];
    foreach($IDs as $ID) {
       if(isset($_POST['user-field' . $ID . '-updated'])){
            $value = $_POST['user-field' . $ID . '-updated'];
            $sql = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET Users = '$value' WHERE id = $ID";
            $q = $db->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(); 
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: I fail to see what changed.

Comment: This does not help the OP with his question.

Comment: I see this: $q->execute($db->prepare($sql)); may be in error ? And string $value is not quoted.

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake, but obviously that is not real OP's code there in question, but some fake showing the idea.

Comment: Yeah nothings changed here. I'm sort of asking for someone to fix my code to do what I want, which maybe isn't what Stack Overflow is good for.  The foreach part can't distinguish which ID goes to which user-count. That's the problem.

Comment: `</input>` is wrong. `input` is a **Void** tag and closes using `/>` or `>` just not with `</input>` - (if OP uses it does not means we have to ;) ) Also `value="` must end with an appropriate `"`.

Answer (score 1):

*Might Be Solution :*

```
  var row = $(this).parents(\"tr:first\")
  or
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');

  var id = row.find('input[name=id]' ).val();
  alert(id);
```

Comment: I have used this jQuery technique to collate all the values into a hidden input field.   However in this case, I was curious if there was a "pure" PHP/HTML way.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML Change

```
 <input type="hidden" name="ID">
```

to

```
 <input type="hidden" name="ID[]">
```

do this with every input in the loop

and you action's PHP page will receive $_POST values in array

1) if name="ID"    the $_POST['ID'] = string;

2) if name="ID[]"    the $_POST['ID'] = array of string;
then you can loop setup something like this

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($_POST['ID'] as $k => $v) {
  // do something
  // like $sql = "update `table` set a = b where id = '{$v}';";
  $counter++;
}
```

This technique helps me a lot :)